# Repeating same data in GridLayout for all Adapter items

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

In Grid Layout I am populating 46 data(Name and Image) but only first 6 data repeating again and again.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View grid;
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      if (convertView == null) {

          grid = new View(mContext);
          grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
          TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imgGrid);
          textView.setText(web[position]);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         // imageView.setBackgroundResource(web[position]);
          Glide.with(mContext).load(Imageid[position]).into(imageView);
      } else {
          grid = (View) convertView;//setBackground(Imageid[position]);
      }

      return grid;
  }
```

Comment: please paste your complete code activity code and adapter code and your complete xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ViewHolder** for initialise Grid cell as give below

```
 public class Viewholder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView
    }
```

and change your **getView()** method like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Viewholder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new Viewholder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list_item, null);

       holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
     holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgGrid);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(web[position]);
      holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
           Glide.with(mContext).load(Imageid[position]).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh. I dont have 15 repo so i have ticked mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it gets Recycled when you scroll.

**Do Something Like This**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Holder holder;
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  if (convertView == null) {

      holder = new Holder();
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
      holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
      holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgGrid);
      convertView.setTag(holder);

  } else {
      holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  holder.textView.setText(web[position]);
  holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  Glide.with(mContext).load(Imageid[position]).into(holder.imageView);
  return grid;
}
class Holder{
   TextView textView;
   ImageView imageView;
}
```

I hope this will help.